# FireBase getAuth and onAuthStateChanged is not in "firebase/auth" import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to learn and use getAuth(), onAuthStateChanged() methods from "firebase/auth"
But in the folder of node_modules/firebase/auth doesnt include those methods.
It seems like changing dirs depending on versions of firebase.
My Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.16.13",
    "firebase": "^9.0.2",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
```

By the firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) it sais that i should use `import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";`
I searched and found that `"firebase/firebase-auth";` folder has included `getAuth` method but when i try to use `import {getAuth} from "firebase/firebase-auth";` it gives me an error states `firebase/firebase-auth` file is not exported. 
What did I miss? 
How i can use getAuth and onAuthStateChanged methods with this dependencies? 
thank you for advices
Firebase.js:

```
// import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
//import {getAuth} from "firebase/firebase-auth";
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";


// onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
//     // Check for user status
// });

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGIN_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})


export const auth = getAuth(app);

export default app
```

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: Why are you trying to import `getAuth` twice? The first one doesn't look valid

Comment: @Phil i am not trying just here to show I uncommented both of them to tell u that both of them are not working!

Comment: Is it an error or warning? I used to similar get warnings in JS project (in Webstorm). Worked perfectly in TS project, still trying to debug the JS one. Also why do you have compat imports as well? Use either one ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i have tried every posibiliies, nothing worked. The problem is here that I dont have gethAuth() function that exported from firebase/auth. And documentation is saying that I should use that function from firebase/auth directory

Comment: Try `npm ci` and can you share a screenshot of the warning/error? Does the app run when you serve it locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import './App.css';

// import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 
  authDomain:
  databaseURL: 
  projectId: 
  storageBucket: 
  messagingSenderId: 
  appId: 
};


initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
            setUser(user);
            // ...
          } else {
            // User is signed out
            // ...
            setUser(null)
            }
          }
        );

  return <>{user ? 
  <><p>Welcome</p><button onClick={() => signOut(auth)}>Google Logout</button></>
  : <><p>Enjoy</p>
  <button onClick={() =>  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
                  .then((result) => {
                    // The signed-in user info.
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    const user = result.user;
                    // ...
                  }).catch((error) => {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    const errorMessage = error.message;
                    // The email of the user's account used.
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    const email = error.email;
                    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
                    // ...
                  })}>
                      Sign in with Google
                    </button>
  </>}</>
}
```